# Keep track of the terminal output of a booting router device

Tags: python, process, operating-system

I am developing a *python script* which *reboots* a cisco router (Access point), and I want to capture the booting log.

But I am not able to caputre the `reboot log`.

When the device is rebooting, what I've tried is to use the subprocess module in this way:

```
output=subprocess.Popen(ap1.reload_ap(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

`ap1.reload_ap()` will reboot the device but it doesn't return anything.

So I've tried to redirect the process outuput to the standard output in order to display the booting log on the terminal after executing the script though `subprocess.PIPE`.

However I am not able to keep track of this booting log using subprocess.

Is there any way to capture the AP booting log to terminal or in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting a system starts with a system/kernel call to [reboot](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/reboot.htm), that's all your process does, the whole rebooting thing happens in the kernel space, that is really out of the reach of your Python script, which runs in the user space.

So with:

```
output=subprocess.Popen(ap1.reload_ap(),stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

You'll be able to just see the output of the reboot system call, nothing else.

On the other hand, the possibility that your Python interpreter is terminated before the system shutdown all processes is very high.

You should read [How does the system shutdown of a Linux kernel work internally?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally) for a better understanding.

## Alternative

You can't get the logs the way you want, but the system will still generate logs, so you can read such logs using Python after a reboot was completed. This might help: [How to find out from the logs what caused system shutdown?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown)

## Recommended reading.

[What is difference between User space and Kernel space?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87625/what-is-difference-between-user-space-and-kernel-space)